# Where to store json string in word document?

Tags: c#, json, word-addins

I would like to implement WordAddin.
I need to have json list related in my word document.
My functionality search word document and base on some criteria crate json string.

I would like to store this json string in word document and use it later if needed. It would be perfect to easy store and easy get this json.
I want have all data in word document, so separate files or database are not options.

My question is: where to store this json string?

Possible solutions I can see are :

- Save on document as text and then hide and protect this text
- Save to file and attach this file to word document (protect and hide)

Is there some better place where could I store data like this in word document?

Comment: You can add custom properties to Word documents, create one, for example called `MyJSON` and set it to the value you need. Not sure if there's a maximum size though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each Microsoft Word document has metadatas and properties. I would recommend to store your Json into one of these.

Here's some examples on how to do it:

- [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ro-ro/library/dhxe2d75(v=vs.140).aspx)
- [Accessing Excel Custom Document Properties programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137763/accessing-excel-custom-document-properties-programmatically)
- [How do I add custom properties to a Word doc with .NET 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329837/how-do-i-add-custom-properties-to-a-word-doc-with-net-4)

Note that properties can be read by the users (if they know what they are searching for).